# undefined method title in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been attempting to make a pretty simple blog application (thought it would be a fun starting point in ruby on rails) and have come into an issue while trying to create a new post. the error I get when loading it on my server is NoMethodError in Posts#show and says the method title is not defined in the show.html.erb file

this is my new.html.rb

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

my post_controller.rb

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new 
    @post = Post.new
  end
  def create
    @post =Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end 

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def show 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

my show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

<div><%= @post.body %></div>
```

and my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: Move your show method in PostsController above `private`

Answer (score 0):

create a method and call it in before_action, so you can set post before the show, and also for edit, update and destroy method

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show]

  def index
  end

  def new 
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post =Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end 

  def show
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def set_post 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```